# can't write into file php no error

Tags: php, file, text-files

I am trying to write data into a text file from php using `fwrite` or `file_put_contents`. Although both `fwrite` and `file_put_contents` return 20 indicating Write operation successful and that 20 bytes were written into the file, but i can't find anything in the file. What might be the issue??

- My file is writable.
- PHP is able to find my file.
- I have even made the file wriable in $file_write_handle.

SO what is the problem here??

```
<?php

$file_name = "user_notes.txt";

$file_write_handle = fopen($file_name,'w');

$data = " i am a disco dancer";

if(file_exists($file_name))
{
    echo "exist";   
}else{
    echo "absent";
}

echo "&nbsp";


if(is_writable($file_name))
{
    echo "writable";
}else {
    echo "cant write";
}

$fw=fwrite($file_write_handle, $data);
echo "fw result" . $fw . "<br/>";

$fpc=file_put_contents($file_name, $data);
echo "fpc result : " . $fpc;
fclose($file_write_handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved as i was working on a local server and the file were being written and stored in the server and not on the local machine.